# Invoke an action for a Datagrid cell independent from Row action

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, action

I have a `datagrid` where the first column is constant for all the rows. 
I would like following behavior:

1. When user double-clicks on any cell of the row (excluding first cell), `action A` is invoked knowing which row is selected. This is event-based (triggers an event).
2. When user double-clicks on first cell of any row, `action B` is invoked knowing which row is selected.

To do this, I wrote following code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding source}" MouseDoubleClick="doubleClick">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="♣" Foreground="{Binding Path=color}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                 <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FirstCellCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=dataGrid}"/>
                 </i:EventTrigger>
             </i:Interaction.Triggers>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Label" Binding="{Binding label, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Point (1.) works fine, but (2.) does not trigger the action.

Am I missing a point here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone would have similar question: I have not found exactly what I want, yet! but there is a work around using code-behind. 
It works for me as follows:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding source}" MouseDoubleClick="doubleClick">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="♣" Foreground="{Binding Path=color}" MouseDown="this_MouseDown"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn>
             <DataGridTextColumn Header="Label" Binding="{Binding label, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I removed the `Interaction.Triggers` and added `MouseDown` to the `TextBlock`.

If anyone would provide an answer using binding, I would appreciate.